# How to get claims in c#?

Tags: c#, authentication, okta

I'm trying to find information on how to configure okta such that I could see information in `httpRequest.HttpContext.User.Claims` in C#. Also, how would I find in C# who the client is? That is, I know how to create an auth server and client in okta but I don't know how to see who that client is in c# when it receives a request. I can see the header which contains the bearer token, but that's about it and that's not really useful for the above purposes (of finding out who the client is and what permissions/claims they have).

Is it possible to configure Okta to get this information? Okta documentation is vast, but doesn't seem to be well enough organized for me to find what I'm looking for. So my question is, can someone point me to the Okta documentation that pertains to these questions?